# Notify Maintenance Team members about new request by inheriting the MaintenanceRequest model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I want to notify all Maintenance Team members when a new request is created inside that particular team.

At the moment I have this functionality handled by an automated action like this:

[image]

Python code:

```py
body_html = """
    ...
""" + record.name + """
    ...
"""

num_of_members = len(record.maintenance_team_id.member_ids)

if num_of_members:
  members_emails = []

  for i in range(num_of_members):
    members_emails.append(record.maintenance_team_id.member_ids[i].email)

  email_to = ",".join(members_emails)

  mail_pool = env['mail.mail']
  values={}
  values.update({'subject': 'New maintenance request - ' + record.company_id.name})
  values.update({'email_to': email_to})
  values.update({'body_html': body_html})
  msg_id = mail_pool.create(values)

  if msg_id:
    mail_pool.send([msg_id])
```

But now I would like to convert this solution to a custom module. What is the correct way to do this?

Should I inherit `maintenance.request`, override the create method and send my email somehow (how exactly?) with hardcoded email body?

```py
class MaintenanceRequest(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'maintenance.request'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        req = super(MaintenanceRequest, self).create(vals)

        body_html = """
            ...
        """ + req.name + """
            ...
        """
        # ...
        if msg_id:
            mail_pool.send([msg_id])

        return req
```

Or there is a way to hook myself to a premade function for sending notification and just tell it to run also for the team members?  I don't want to add all of them as followers (because they would get spammed with unnecessary updates about the request) - only to notify them about the new request and then they can follow it if they needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `mail.template` in the custom module and set the members email list dynamically in it. There are already some simple mail template examples in Odoo to look into.

In Code you just have to send the mail by using this template.

```xml
<record id="my_mail_template" model="mail.template">
    <field name="name">My Mail Template</field>
    <field name="partner_to">${",".join(map(str, object.maintenance_team_id.member_ids.mapped('partner_id').ids))}</field>
    <!-- add all other required fields -->
</record>
```

```py
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    record = super().create(values)
    template_id = self.env.ref('my_module.my_mail_template').id
    if template_id:
        record.message_post_with_template(template_id)
    return record
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I have trouble with getting this code to work. No email is send with it. Why did you left super() empty? Here is my models.py: https://pastebin.com/G5AYAPXu. Here is mail_template.xml: https://pastebin.com/wCXy6zNq. And here is manifest: https://pastebin.com/6xC1XyTH

Comment: Empty `super()` is possible since Python 3. Call your class `MaintenanceRequest` and remove `_name` completely. The rest looks okay to me.

Comment: So I did that but sadly still no email is generated. This is my `models.py` now: https://pastebin.com/a3T8VgDW. New email template is visible inside developer UI.

Comment: Did you check in Settings/technical/Email/Emails? Maybe something is wrong with the generated mail?

Comment: Yes, there is no email over there.

Comment: After restarting Odoo service once again I now get an error when I'm trying to create new request: https://pastebin.com/1V3mSmGJ

Comment: Look into the log to get the full error. But atleast Odoo tried to render one, so you're on the right way.

Comment: You are right. Inside logs `/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log` I saw this: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'odoo.api.maintenance.request object' has no attribute 'partner_id'`. It turned out that it was problem with this line of code inside mail template: `<field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>`. I removed it and now it is working fine (I had to delete previously created template as well and then load module again).